# Page up/down doesn't scroll the page when a textarea has focus

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

When using <kbd>PG UP</kbd> or <kbd>PG DOWN</kbd> when a `<textarea>` has focus, the event is not sent to the parent document, thus it *doesn't* scroll the page. **How to make it scroll the page?**

```html
a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
<textarea>hello</textarea><br>
a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.blur()` allows to propagate the PG UP / PG DOWN to the page, and thus it allows to scroll the page.

```js
$('textarea').keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 33 || e.keyCode == 34) {   
            $('textarea').blur();
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
<textarea>hello</textarea><br>
a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
```